# Where Datetime NOT IN Between Select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, where-in

I would like to know how to select a number of rows where my datetime is not in between a select.

My Current Select looks like this:

```
SELECT LOG.*
FROM LOG
WHERE   LOG.[date]      >=  @startDate
AND     (LOG.[date]     <=  @endDate OR @endDate IS NULL)
AND     LOG.[date] NOT IN BETWEEN ANY PAIR FROM (SELECT ADMINaction.Start,ADMINaction.Ende 
                               FROM ADMINaction 
                               WHERE     ADMINaction.Start      >=  @startDate
                               AND      (ADMINaction.Ende   <=  @endDate OR @endDate IS NULL))
```

But this is not a valid query.

How do i need to modify this to make it valid?

---

Edit

> Q: Would that sub-query always return only one result?
>
> A: NO, the sub-query can contain any number of results

Comment: Please could you confirm, in your sub-query you specify a `[date]` field, but you are not explicit about which table that is in.  To be more explicit, should it read `ADMINaction.[date]` or `LOG.[date]`?  And would that sub-query ***always*** return only one result?

Comment: @MatBailie thanks for your asking, i updated my Question

Comment: If the sub-query returns 10 results, would your pseudo code be better written as `LOG.[date] NOT BETWEEN "ANY PAIR FROM (your sub query)"`, or does each row in `LOG` need to be related to just one single row in `ADMINaction`?

Comment: @MatBailie you are right

Comment: Sorry, I asked should this be A or B?  And you answered Yes?

Comment: @MatBailie oh Sorry :'( it is **A** (i also updated my Query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, you want a `left join` or `not exists`:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM LOG l
WHERE l.[date] >=  @startDate AND
      (l.[date] <=  @endDate OR @endDate IS NULL) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ADMINaction a
                  WHERE l.[date] >= a.Start AND
                        (l.[date] <= a.Ende OR a.Ende IS NULL)
                 );
```

This returns the rows from `log` where the log date has no corresponding time interval in `ADMINaction`.  That seems to be the intentions of your query.

Comment: I can't be sure, but it *appears* that the OP filters the `ADMINaction` based on its `[date]` field.  This doesn't do that.  As there are no express relationships between `LOG.[date]` and `ADMINaction.[date]`, this answer may or may not be correct.

Comment: @MatBailie . . . I don't think so (although it is possible).  It would be odd for that table to have two date ranges.  I think the relationship between the dates is given by the `FROM` clause in the subquery and the weird `NOT IN BETWEEN` attempt at logic.

Comment: Indeed, it may or may not be the case, it's ambiguous in the OP.  But, equally, unless this ambiguity is addressed in the answer or by the OP, the answer is simply ignoring an aspect of the question without a reason.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i'm really sorry for the confusion, i mixed things up as i created the simple problem for SO i fixed my query and also add some informations

Comment: @WiiMaxx . . . That was what I thought you were trying to do and that is what this answer addresses.

Answer (score 1):

If you are 100% sure that the query you use to determine the Start and End dates only returns one record, you can do this (to be sure, you could include a `TOP 1` in the inner `SELECT`):

```
SELECT *
FROM LOG CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT Start,Ende 
     FROM ADMINaction 
     WHERE     [date]     >=  @startDate
     AND      ([date]     <=  @endDate OR @endDate IS NULL)
) DateFilter
WHERE   LOG.[date]      >=  @startDate
AND     (LOG.[date]     <=  @endDate OR @endDate IS NULL)
AND     LOG.[date] NOT BETWEEN DateFilter.Start AND DateFilter.Ende
```

In case your ADMINaction table only contains 1 record, you could simplify this query to:

```
SELECT *
FROM LOG CROSS JOIN ADMINaction
WHERE   [date]      >=  @startDate
AND     ([date]     <=  @endDate OR @endDate IS NULL)
AND     [date] NOT BETWEEN Start AND Ende
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I just copied OP's query and forgot to remove the `IN`.

Comment: @Dan sorry for the confusion my ADMINaction can return any number of rows